# Output multiple arguments to string like console.log in javascript like Go's fmt.Sprintln

Tags: javascript

I want to output some arguments to string for debug,

```js
a=3
b="b"
c={d:"d", e:1}
console.log(a,b,c)
```

Is there a function to convert a,b,c to a readable string instead output in console?

```js
a=3
b="b"
c={d:"d", e:1}
s=sprintln(a,b,c)  // is there a similar function like Go's Sprintln?
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can print out an object instead. That way you will see the property names:

```
console.log({a, b, c});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** method, which is **[supported in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=json)**. Note that you can also optionally set the indentation, so that it looks exactly like a regular JSON object:

```js
var a = 3;
var b = "b";
var c = {
  d: "d",
  e: 1
}

console.log(JSON.stringify({a, b, c}, null, 4));
```

Note that this will work for alerts too:

```js
var a = 3;
var b = "b";
var c = {
  d: "d",
  e: 1
}

alert(JSON.stringify({a, b, c}, null, 4));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I just want the output like console.log(), the JSON output is not necessary, is it possible?